# Flutter Dynamic Theming

Tags: dart, flutter

What is the best way to go about dynamically changing the theme of a Flutter app? For example, if the user changes the color to red, I want the theme to instantly be changed to red. I can't find anything very helpful online except one guy said to use the BLOC pattern, which I am not familiar with it. I'd like to hear your guys thoughts on the issue. Thanks!

My current code structure:

```
var themeData = ThemeData(
    fontFamily: 'Raleway',
    primaryColor: Colors.blue,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    accentColor: Colors.blue);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: Constants.appName,
      theme: themeData,
      home: CheckAuth(), //CheckAuth returns MyHomePage usually
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title, @required this.uid}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final String uid;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    ...build and stuff
    }
```

Comment: what aspects of the app do you want to include in theming? Also it would be of great help to others if you could add a small piece of code you've got.

Comment: Just changing the color and the brightness (dark/bright). Don't have much specific code to offer, just a super basic app basically.

Comment: You'll basically need to turn such config (bg color, font color, size, etc.,) into variables, and update them on certain events. Hard to say what and how could you achieve based on the info available, but hope you get the point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [InhertedWidget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) if you like (instead of BLOC) - Basically it is used to access parent widget anywhere from the tree.

So what you should do is

1. create `InheritedWidget`, somewhere in top of tree [from where you want the effect of theme to take place]
2. wrap it around `Theme` widget
3. expose a method to switch theme, by passing the ThemeData you want to replace it with.

Here is some code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

var themeData = ThemeData(
    fontFamily: 'Raleway',
    primaryColor: Colors.blue,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    accentColor: Colors.blue
);

void main() {
  runApp(
    ThemeSwitcherWidget(
      initialTheme: themeData,
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class ThemeSwitcher extends InheritedWidget {
  final _ThemeSwitcherWidgetState data;

  const ThemeSwitcher({
    Key key,
    @required this.data,
    @required Widget child,
  })  : assert(child != null),
        super(key: key, child: child);

  static _ThemeSwitcherWidgetState of(BuildContext context) {
    return (context. dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType(ThemeSwitcher)
            as ThemeSwitcher)
        .data;
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(ThemeSwitcher old) {
    return this != old;
  }
}

class ThemeSwitcherWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final ThemeData initialTheme;
  final Widget child;

  ThemeSwitcherWidget({Key key, this.initialTheme, this.child})
      : assert(initialTheme != null),
        assert(child != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  _ThemeSwitcherWidgetState createState() => _ThemeSwitcherWidgetState();
}

class _ThemeSwitcherWidgetState extends State<ThemeSwitcherWidget> {
  ThemeData themeData;

  void switchTheme(ThemeData theme) {
    setState(() {
      themeData = theme;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    themeData = themeData ?? widget.initialTheme;
    return ThemeSwitcher(
      data: this,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeSwitcher.of(context).themeData,
      home: CheckAuth(),
    );
  }
}
```

I have wrapped ThemeSwitcherWidget around MaterialApp so the effect is throughout the app (even when you push new route with Navigator).

Use `ThemeSwitcher.of(context).switchTheme(themeData)` anywhere below ThemeSwithcerWidget to change the theme.

In question's case it should call `ThemeSwitcher.of(context).switchTheme(Theme.of(context).copyWith(primaryColor: Colors.red))` to switch primary color to red throught out the app, for eg.  on some button click

EDIT: replaced `inheritFromWidgetOfExactType` -> `dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType`, since it is deprecated - as pointed by [Phoca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2549828/phoca) in comments.

Comment: hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm unsure of how to implement this is my current app. I updated my question with my current code structure.

Comment: I've added some. Hope that might help.

Comment: Getting errors. "Tried calling: switchTheme(Instance of 'ThemeData')", "NoSuchMethodError: The method 'switchTheme' was called on null."

Comment: Also don't know what to pass in as 'data'

Comment: for the first comment - that means you are calling `ThemeSwitcher.of(context).switchTheme(..)` above `ThemeSwitcherWidget` in the tree. if you are using my example code snippet. you should call this only below CheckAuth widget. If you are already doing that then, you are passing wrong context to ThemeSwitcher.of() method [I assume you might be passing context from MyApp build method, you should pass CheckAuth widget's context]

Comment: for seconf comment - if you use `ThemeSwitcherWidget` it will pass data (that is state of the widget to ThemeSwitcher), you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: I have run into the issue of child widgets don't carry the custom theme. For instance, my main page theme looks good but them if I launch another page **Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SettingsScreen()),
                  );** The new page just has the default theme. I'm guessing there is a simple fix.

Comment: Edited code.
fix: wrapping `ThemeSwitcherWidget` around MaterialApp instead inside it, for theme to have effect after new route has been pushed through Navigator. Changed `ThemeSwithcerWidget` API - added initialTheme which is mandatory to provide

Comment: for this to have effect after the app is closed and reopened you will have to use [shared_prefernce plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences) to store last theme config and loading it when runApp is called.

Comment: i am using you snippet but its re sets and comes to first home page after changing theme

Comment: @BhargavSejpal I think that is because when you switch the theme, the child are being rebuilt. Hard to find what the issue is.

Comment: hello from 2021: `inheritFromWidgetOfExactType` does not exist anymore and was replaced by `dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType` in Flutter 2

Comment: @Phoca Thanks for pointing out this, have updated the answere.

Answer (score 7):

Using [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package: 
`theme_changer.dart`

```
var darkTheme = ThemeData.dark();
var lightTheme= ThemeData.light();

class ThemeChanger extends ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeData _themeData;
  ThemeChanger(this._themeData);

  get getTheme => _themeData;
  void setTheme(ThemeData theme) {
    _themeData = theme;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

`main.dart`

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ThemeChanger(lightTheme)),
      ],
      child: MaterialAppWithTheme(),
    );
  }
}

class MaterialAppWithTheme extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Provider.of<ThemeChanger>(context);
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: theme.getTheme,
      home: FirstScreen(),
    );
  }
```

`first_screen.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import './theme_changer.dart'

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    var _themeProvider=Provider.of<ThemeChanger>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title:Text("First Screen"),),
      body:Container(width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
           height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
           child:Center(
                child:FlatButton(child:Text("Press me"). onPressed:(){
                  _themeProvider.setTheme(_themeProvider.getTheme==lightTheme?darkTheme:lightTheme);
                })
           ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change the theme using [`setState`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) or [`ValueListenableBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html) dynamically without any extension.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Basics',
    home: StartScreen(),
  ));
}

class StartScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const StartScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StartScreen> createState() => _StartScreenState();
}

class _StartScreenState extends State<StartScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final notifier = ValueNotifier(ThemeController.type);

    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: notifier,
      builder: (BuildContext context, ThemeType value, Widget? child) {
        print(value.name);
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeController.data,
          child: Scaffold(
              body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      int i = (value.index + 1) % ThemeType.values.length;
                      ThemeController.select(ThemeType.values[i]);
                    });
                  },
                  child: const Text('Change Theme(setState)'),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    int i = (value.index + 1) % ThemeType.values.length;
                    ThemeController.select(ThemeType.values[i]);
                    notifier.value = ThemeController.type;
                  },
                  child: const Text('Change Theme(Notifier)'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

enum ThemeType {
  dark,
  light,
  system,
}

class ThemeController {
  static ThemeType _type = ThemeType.system;
  static ThemeType get type => _type;
  static ThemeData _themeData = _getData(ThemeType.system);
  static ThemeData get data => _themeData;

  static ThemeData select(ThemeType type) {
    _type = type;
    _themeData = _getData(type);
    return _themeData;
  }

  static ThemeData _getData(ThemeType themeType) {
    Brightness brightness = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.platformBrightness;
    ThemeType type = themeType == ThemeType.system
        ? ThemeType.values[brightness.index]
        : themeType;
    switch (type) {
      case ThemeType.dark:
        return ThemeData.dark();
      case ThemeType.light:
        return ThemeData.light();
      default:
        return _themeData;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how to implement the dynamic Theme changing in Your App:

1.You should Change your `MyApp` into `Stateful` widget to enable the class to rebuild again when the color changes:

```
 var _primary = Colors.blue ; // This will hold the value of the app main color

 var themeData = ThemeData(
 fontFamily: 'Raleway',
 primaryColor: _primary, // so when the rebuilds the color changes take effect
 brightness: Brightness.light,
 backgroundColor: Colors.white,
 accentColor: Colors.blue);

 void main() => runApp(new App());

 class App extends StatefulWidget {
 App({Key key,}) :

 super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppState createState() => new _AppState();

  static void setTheme(BuildContext context, Color newColor) {
  _AppState state = context.ancestorStateOfType(TypeMatcher<_AppState>());
   state.setState(() {
     state._primary = newColor;
    });
  }
}
```

2.The static method `setTheme` will be the one responsible for color changing :

```
  class _AppState extends State<App> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
  title: Constants.appName,
  theme: themeData,
  home: CheckAuth(), //CheckAuth returns MyHomePage usually
  );
 }
}
```

3.When You want to change the theme color from anywhere from your code call this method:

```
  App.setTheme(context, Colors.blue);
```

Comment: Awesome solution! Now I don't return MaterialApp by main() but from main I return a statefull widget that return MaterialApp. In the build() of this new class i use "theme: App_IsLightMode! ? App_LightTheme : App_DarkTheme," and I expose a method to reach its setstate so when I need to change the theme I call the setstate of that new statefull widget.

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach (to me) is to achieve this is to make use of `Stream` with `InheritedWidget`.

The basic idea is to use an `InheritedWidget` with a `StreamController`, and wrap your `MaterialApp` (or a subtree of your app) with a `StreamBuilder` which gets the `Stream` from the `StreamController` from the `InheritedWidget`.

A complete tested working code sample as follows:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData(
  colorSchemeSeed: Colors.amber,
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
);

ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
  colorSchemeSeed: Colors.blue,
  brightness: Brightness.light,
);

void main() {
  runApp(
    CustomTheme(
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<ThemeData>(
      initialData: lightTheme,
      stream: CustomTheme.of(context)!.streamController.stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) => MaterialApp(
        theme: snapshot.data,
        home: const HomeScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomTheme extends InheritedWidget {
  CustomTheme({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key, child: child);

  final Widget child;
  final StreamController<ThemeData> streamController = StreamController();

  static CustomTheme? of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<CustomTheme>();
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(CustomTheme oldWidget) {
    return oldWidget != this;
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CustomTheme customTheme = CustomTheme.of(context)!;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Custom Theme Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                customTheme.streamController.add(darkTheme);
              },
              child: const Text('DARK'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                customTheme.streamController.add(lightTheme);
              },
              child: const Text('LIGHT'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have used [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) plugin and used  Get.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.(dark/system/light)); it works perfectly for me

First u have to add the [get plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/get) by following the installing guide

then in main change

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return GetMaterialApp(
  title: 'Add Your Title',
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme:_lightTheme,
  darkTheme: _darkTheme,
  home: login(),
  );
 }
}
```

ON Tap function

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';


             

  onTap: () {
       Get.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.dark);
             setState(() async {
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(
                     context,
                     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => super.widget));
                });
              }
```

I have two button for both themes and onTap i have just add the line

Get.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.dark) for dark mode ,
Get.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.dark) for light mode