# flutter change the color of utils const color , in the app screen using button

Tags: flutter, colors, constants, uicolor

I wrote a big software, I tried to use 2 main colors for the whole software. I want to change the overall color of the software by pressing a button. I need your help.

on the lib/utils:
SO:they are not in the class,

const d = Color.fromARGB(255, 184, 233, 8);

const w = Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);

on every page i made i used it like under code to change colors that i used:

color:d,

or

color:w,

now i made button and want to use it like:

```
AppBar(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25.0),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(25.0))),
              toolbarHeight: 40,
              backgroundColor: d,
              foregroundColor: w,
              bottomOpacity: 0.1,
              centerTitle: false,
              title: SvgPicture.asset(
                'assets/ic_instagram.svg',
                color: primaryColor,
                height: 25,
              ),
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.mail,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 191),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => colorset(),
                        ),
                      );
                    });
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.mail,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 132, 255),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      d.update(d: Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 132, 255));
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

how is it possible to change the color of const values in utils?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change your color variables why don't you just remove the const?

Use const for variables that do not change anymore (e.g. PI)

```
Color w = Color.fromARGB(255, 184, 233, 8);
```

Comment: how to change it with the new color using the button?

Comment: You could create a wrapper widget around your app and call the state change on it (with Provider, InheritedWidget, etc.). Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54757480/flutter-dynamic-theming

Comment: worked , tnx . but with every refresh the change will remove

Comment: set state will change it on running app after rerunnig the app i get the same color